# How to prevent the browser's refresh button from reloading already filled input data

Tags: php, html, post

I'm building my website in PHP and HTML and in a "sales" section where the user must fill out fields and upload them, once uploaded if the user wants to fill them again with other data and presses the browser refresh button (or any browser) the data is uploaded again.

I verified that if the data was already in the Mysql table, I cannot load it, but when I delete it, if I refresh it, it loads it again.

```
mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO stock (stock)
VALUES  ('{$_POST['idstock']}')" );
```

Comment: You must provide some code to formulate a response

Comment: This is somewhat the user's fault - why would they press refresh? But you can mitigate against it - make sure your application already presents them with another blank form, so they don't have to, or it redirects them to another page, so they can't.

Comment: Maybe deleting the "confirm" button from the Chrome pop-up that appears when the user presses refresh. Don't know how to do it...

Comment: No, you _want_ that pop-up, because it is trying to persuade the user not to post the data again. But users can dismiss it and tell it not to appear again, and to just do the re-post automatically. _That's_ when you start to have problems. Anyway you can't control that, it's a browser feature, controlled by the user. But again, users should a) know better, and b) be directed away from being tempted to do so, by one of the routes I suggested in my first comment.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is directly related to MySQL or Google Chrome? Can you share the code involved?

Comment: typically after issuing a `POST` request that is processed by the PHP script you then issue a GET request ( `header('Location: somepage.php')` ) to redirect - when the user have been redirected the Refresh button will no longer cause the POST request to be re-sent/processed

Comment: `I have the same problem in Mozilla`...well then it's clearly nothing to do with chrome is it...I removed the tag

Comment: Anyway don't put code or other important information into the comments. Always [edit] your question so that everything relevant is clear and in one place. Comments are mainly for us to make brief suggestions or requests for updates. It's not intended as a discussion forum. See also [ask] Thanks

Comment: Ty, is my first time here. My bad

Comment: No problem. Anyway the possible solutions are still the same as I mentioned in my first comment

Comment: Please share more details. The code you've shared so far is highly vulnerable for SQL injections, but does not contain anything that would relate to "I cannot load it"